# Power function exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to find the power function for a test. 
I know that the power function is calculated by $\beta(0) = P_0(x \in R)$ where $R$ is the rejection region. What I know about this test is that $X \sim Exp(\beta) \\H_0: \beta = \beta_0 \quad H_1: \beta > \beta_0 \\ Y_n = min(X_1,..,X_n) \quad Y \sim Exp(\frac{\beta}{n})$

What I have tried until now, is that I think that $P_0(x \in R) = P_0(Y_n > c_n) $ since in this scenario the null hypothesis is rejected if all values for $X$ are higher than $C_n$. However I am unsure how to apply the properties of the exponential distribution to $Y_n$ and $c_n$

Comment: I'm not saying it is wrong, but how do you conclude that the power function is $\mathbb{P}_0(Y_n < c_n)$? There is no description of what kind of test.

Comment: @Siron I think I have specified in my question that $X_1,..,X_n \sim Exp(\beta)$ I concluded this because for this scenario $Y_n = min(X_1,..,X_n)$ thus I thought that .. although I don't have proof for it yet

Comment: Yes, that is the reason that I asked my question. Why do you think $\mathbb{P}(Y_n > c_n)$? If this is indeed true then it is not hard to compute the power function.

Comment: Ok. Yes I gained more insight. For now I know that this is the region for which $H_0$ will be rejected. Because $H_0$ whill be rejected when the value for the test statistic of the hypothesis's distribution is smaller than the alpha level. So thus I should calculate this region using the information I know about this is distributed? But will I need to calculate test statistics of the exponential distribution? I know what the region means but I don"t get how to get further..

Answer (score 3):

Based on your information I think the question has to be interpret as

Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d exponentially distributed with an unknown parameter $\beta$. Suppose we want to test $H_0: \beta = \beta_0$ versus $H_1: \beta > \beta_0$. Suppose the test is performed by rejecting $H_0$ when $Y = \min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}>c$. Compute the power function for this test.

Since $Y \sim \mbox{Exp}\left(\frac{\beta}{n}\right)$, we can easily compute the power function
 $$\mathbb{P}(Y_n > c) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(Y_n < c) = 1- F_{Y_n}(c),$$
where $F_{Y_n}$ is the distribution function of an exponential distribution with parameter $\beta/n$. Please correct me if my interpretation of the question is incorrect.