# Power function for a Uniformly Most Powerful Test

Tags: probability, self-learning, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, gamma-distribution

## Question

Suppose I am interested in the following problem :
\begin{align}
    H_0 : \ \theta \geq \theta_0 \ \text{versus} \ H_1 : \ \theta < \theta_0
\end{align}
If $X \sim B(\theta,1)$, $-\sum_{i=1}^n ln(x_i) \sim Gamma(n,1/\theta)$ and the critical region for this hypothesis test is \emph{given} as :
\begin{align}
 -\sum_{i=1}^n ln(x_i) &> \theta_0^{-1}G_n^{-1}(1-\alpha) 
\end{align}
Where $G_n^{-1}$ is the quantile of order p of a Gamma (n,1) distribution.

I am asked to find explicit expressions for the probability of type 1 error and the probability of type 2 error.

## Partial solution

I've written the critical function $\phi(x)$ :

\begin{align}
    \phi(x) =   
    \begin{cases}
    1 \ \text{if} \ -\sum_{i=1}^n ln(X_i) > \theta_0^{-1}G_n^{-1}(1-\alpha) \\
    0 \ \text{if} \ -\sum_{i=1}^n ln(X_i) < \theta_0^{-1}G_n^{-1}(1-\alpha) \\
    \gamma \ \text{if} \ -\sum_{i=1}^n ln(X_i) = \theta_0^{-1}G_n^{-1}(1-\alpha)
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
With $\gamma$ a probability.

The power function of a test is then defined as :
\begin{align}
    \pi(\theta) = E_\theta(\phi(X_n) \forall \theta \in \Theta
\end{align}

The probability of committing a type I error is $\alpha$ because :
\begin{align}
    \alpha &= E_{\theta_0}(\phi(x) \\
    &= 1 \times P(-\sum_{i=1}^n ln(X_i) > \theta_0^{-1}G_n^{-1}(1-\alpha)) + \gamma \times P(-\sum_{i=1}^n ln(X_i) = \theta_0^{-1}G_n^{-1}(1-\alpha))
\end{align}

I have noted that :
\begin{align}
P(-\sum_{i=1}^n ln(X_i) > \theta_0^{-1}G_n^{-1}(1-\alpha)) \\
\Leftrightarrow P(\sum_{i=1}^n ln(X_i) < G_{n,\theta_0^{-1}}(1-\alpha)) = \alpha
\end{align}
Therefore I found an explicit expression for the probability of type I error :
\begin{align}
P(\sum_{i=1}^n ln(X_i) < G_{n,\theta_0^{-1}}(1-\alpha)) = \alpha
\end{align}
This is assuming that $P(-\sum_{i=1}^n ln(X_i) = \theta_0^{-1}G_n^{-1}(1-\alpha)) = 0$ which I think is a reasonable assumption to make if the distribution is continuous, the probability of it taking a finite value is 0.

Nevertheless, I don't know how to compute the type 2 error which is defined as :
\begin{align}
    1 - E_{\theta_1}(\phi(x))
\end{align}

N.B : I am asking this question for a homework therefore I am looking for hints rather than solutions.

Edit :

#### Finding the power function :

Actually, based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772904/power-function-exponential-distribution) I've found that :

\begin{align}
    P\Big(-\sum ln(X_i) > \theta_0^{-1}G^{-1}_n(1-\alpha \Big) 
    &= 1 - P\Big(-\sum ln(X_i) < G_{n,\theta_0^{-1}}^{-1}(1-\alpha) \Big) \\
    &= 1 -G_{n,\theta_0^{-1}}
\end{align}

There is no closed form expression for the cdf of a Gamma distribution but I can plot the values of the power function for a sample size $n=20$ and a true parameter $\theta_0=2$ with the following line of R code :

> plot(seq(1:100),1-pgamma(seq(1:100),20,0.5))

Which gives the following plot for my power function :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As known, $T=\Sigma_i \log X_i$ is CSS for $\theta$ thus, using a well known theorem on regular Exponential families, the critical region (rejection region) is

$$\mathbb{P}[T>c|\theta_0]=\alpha$$

knowing the distribution of $Y=-T$   (I prefer to indicate it as $\text{Gamma}(n;\theta)$) you get

$$\mathbb{P}[Y<k|\theta_0]=\alpha$$

Example: testing $H_0=1$ Vs $H_1>1$ with the random sample

$$\{0.6;0.7;0.4\}$$

we know that

$$(2Y|\theta_0=1)=-2\Sigma_i\log X_i\sim\chi_{(6)}^2$$

thus the critical region is

$$-2\Sigma_i\log X_i<1.64$$

As the give observation show:

$$-2\log(0.6\cdot0.7\cdot 0.4)=3.57$$

we cannot reject $H_0$

To evaluate Type II error, without fixing a specific value for $\theta_1$ you have to use the same procedure finding a power function; $\beta$ is its complement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still I'm quite confused. In order to compute the power beta of my test, I'd need to compute the probability that the test statistic is in the critical region assuming that my null hypothesis is true so in the exercice I give above it should be : $P(-\sum ln(X_i) > \theta_0^{-1} G^{-1}_n(1-\alpha)$ but this probability should be 0 because the left side of the inequality should be negative and the right side positive.

Comment: I've edited my original post with a proposal for the power function, which I found reading more about the subject but I am still confused on how to find an expression for type 2 error.